# How do I delete gems for old ruby versions installed by bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I want to free up disk space in my production environment taken up by gems installed for old ruby versions. I don't believe `bundle clean` will work in this instance, because I don't think it cleans out the old gems for other rubies.

These gems are installed via capistrano and are installed in a custom location, rather than system wide. In my `/path/to/my-project/shared/bundle/ruby` dir, I see 2 subdirs - `2.2.0` & `2.3.0`. Since I am now using ruby 2.3, is it safe just to delete the `2.2.0` directory? Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: what production environment are you using? shouldn't them go away after deployment?

Comment: It's rails, and I use capistrano to deploy, but [capistrano doesn't clean anything](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1926) because it would impact the ability to roll back.

Answer (score 3):

Use "sudo gem cleanup" to remove all previously installed gems which respecting all the dependencies be it on old version of ruby. You can see all the gems that ll be removed with command "sudo gem cleanup -d"

Comment: This is interesting - thanks. I forgot to mention that these are installed in a custom location via bundler (q updated now). Do you know if there is a bundler equivalent (I guess not)?

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can remove a specific version of the gem:

```
gem uninstall (gem name here) --version (version number here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to Gemfile.lock and delete all its content. Then you go to Gemfile and delete gems you do not want anymore. After, You type bundle install and it will install just the ones you want.

Comment: I don't think doing this will delete any gems, neither for the current ruby version or the old ones. Also this will result in the latest versions of all gems in Gemfile being installed, which isn't what I want to do. Have I misunderstood something here?